# Port in the core-site.xml file

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, port, hdfs

I tried to create the folder in file system of `HDFS` by means of a command

```
./hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hadoop
```

and as a result I received the following messages

```
13/02/17 09:45:50 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:51 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:52 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:53 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
13/02/17 09:45:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: one/192.168.1.8:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to one/192.168.1.8:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

In the /export/hadoop-1.0.1/conf/core-site.xml file the following is specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://192.168.1.8:9000</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Wanted to specify - whether correct I specified port? If isn't present, tell what it is necessary?

Comment: Can you confirm that the name node is running on 192.168.1.8, and on port 9000?

Answer (score 0):

seems like hadoop daemons are not running. check with     jps